# CSS inbox issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an message inbox using css . The inbox include 2 span which are for recipient and one for subject. I used overflow hidden to hide any characters if the recipient name goes over the width of the span .The issue occurs when recipient character increase, it pushes the subject span further away . I want to make the subject span box stay still in it's position. How can this be done?

Thank you for helping me

See Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QaQAv/

[image]

[image]

html

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/float.css">



 <div class="box15">

 <span class="username"> Hello HelloHelloHello</span>
 <span class="description">Hello</span><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="id_check">
 <p>
 <span class="username">Hello</span>
 <span class="description">Hello</span><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="id_check">
 <p>
 <span class="username">Hello</span>
 <span class="description">Hello</span><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="id_check">
 <p>
 </div>
```

css

```
.box15 {background-color: #71ECA0;height:480px;width: 500px;position: absolute;left: 450px;top: 230px; }
.username {background-color: #7EBA00;height:23px;width: 130px;position: relative;left: 10px;top: 10px;font-size:21px;font-family:Garamond;color: #090E13;overflow:hidden;}
.description {background-color: #7EBA00;height:23px;width: 290px;position: relative;left: 150px;top: 9px;font-size:21px;font-family:Garamond;color: #090E13;overflow:hidden;}
.id_check {background-color: #F6E49C;position: relative;left: 370px;top: 7px;}
```

Comment: This is tabular data, why don't you use a table?

Comment: @flem table is old school.

Comment: @ÖzkanÖZLÜ Tables do have their place, especially (as flem notes) when you're dealing with what appears to be tabular data. Tables are only "bad" when used for site structure.

Comment: @ÖzkanÖZLÜ Don't be fooled by the "table-hate" crowd. Tables are quite practical when used appropriately. Don't reinvent the wheel. If you need to display a table, use a table. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use divs instead of spans. Span is inline element. No width or height effects span's size. You use p element wrongly. Also prepend / before closing > in input tag. Also I suggest you to use relative width values instead of exact values.
http://jsfiddle.net/QaQAv/6/

```
<div class="box15">

 <div class="username"> Hello HelloHelloHello</div>
 <div class="description">Hello</div>
 <div class="checkMe"><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" /></div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <div class="username">Hello</div>
 <div class="description">Hello</div>
 <div class="checkMe"><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" /></div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <div class="username">Hello</div>
 <div class="description">Hello</div>
 <div class="checkMe"><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" /></div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: thank you for helping me but http://jsfiddle.net/QaQAv/4/ , I'm trying to make it into a straight column but the second row is bit everywhere , How can you make it into a column ?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a case where a simple table actually makes more sense - I tend to think of an email inbox as tabular data. Add the `<colgroup>` element so that you can define your column widths in one place:

```
<table class="inbox">
    <colgroup>
        <col />
        <col class="sender" />
        <col class="subject" />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </th>
            <th>
                Sender
            </th>
            <th>
                Subject
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td>
                foo@bar.tld
            </td>
            <td>
                You won some moneys!
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And some simple CSS rules to make it look a little nicer:

```
table.inbox
{
    border: solid 1px #f5f5f5;
    padding:5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.sender
{
    width: 15em;
    text-align: left;
}

th
{
    text-align: left;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 5px;
}

.subject
{
    min-width: 20em;
}

td
{
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pXkyB/

One advantage of using a table is that there are also quite a few JavaScript plugins that make it trivial to sort rows and rearrange columns; jqGrid is the first that comes to mind.

Comment: oh mate thank you tieson . I just fixed the issue few minutes ago by using <div> . all I can say is thank you very much and +1

Comment: @JackRoster Go with what works, but keep in mind that tables do still have perfectly valid uses in HTML.